# Как вывести количество друзей для каждого пользователя

Tags: python, django

### models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    friends_list = models.ManyToManyField('Friends', blank=True, related_name='friends_list') # внешний ключ

class Friends(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user')
    couple = models.ManyToManyField('Couple', blank=True, related_name='couple') # внешний ключ

class Couple(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user1')
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user2')
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from app1.models import Profile, Friends

def user_list(request):
    user_list = Profile.objects.all()
    for user_friend in user_list:
        print(user_friend.friends_list)
    return HttpResponse("132sd")
```

---

(user_friend.friends_list) выводит (app1.Friends.None). Как вывести список пользователей и количество друзей у каждого пользователя.

Comment: print(user_list) что показывает?

Comment: user_friend.friends_list.all() попробуй для вывода друзей пользователя и user_friend.friends_list.count() для вывода количества друзей пользователя

Comment: print(user_list) <QuerySet [<Profile: Profile object (1)>, <Profile: Profile object (2)>, <Profile: Profile object (3)>, <Profile: Profile object (4)>]>

Comment: @VladimirBabaev спасибо теперь выводит как нужно A друзья 2, B друзья 1, C друзья 1, D друзья 0